# Help About Installation Ubuntu

Tags: system-installation

I want to know that can i install ubuntu on compaq presario V2000 laptop.

System Specifications are mentioned below

1. 1 GB of RAM
2. 1.40 GHz Processor
3. Intel Celeron.

And if i install ubuntu with these requirement so kindly advise me that which version of ubuntu is better for my laptop.

Thank You.

Comment: Try Lubuntu 32 bits.

Comment: Can you think that this is helpful for me

Comment: Please clarify your last remark?

Comment: Perhaps you want to know why I advise Lubuntu?  Well, your system has very little RAM, so I think Lubuntu 32 bits (x86) is the obvious choice. For more info, see: http://lubuntu.net.

Comment: That Celeron M (400 MHz bus) processor might lack the PAE flag, but still have PAE capability. You may need to boot with the boot option `forcepae`. See this link, https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Lubuntu/AdvancedMethods#Pentium_M_and_Celeron_M

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I find out which version and derivative of Ubuntu is right for my hardware in terms of minimal system requirements?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/206407/how-do-i-find-out-which-version-and-derivative-of-ubuntu-is-right-for-my-hardwar)

Answer (score 0):

Your system has very little RAM, so I think Lubuntu 32 bits (x86) is the obvious choice. For more info, see: lubuntu.net.

Comment: Dear Sir, Can i install Lubuntu via USB Drive or any Pedrive.

Comment: yes. Instructions how to install can be found on the website i sent previously. Please also pay attention to the remark made by Sufodus.

Comment: Dear Sir, Good evening can you please help me.

Comment: with your guidance i have successfully installed ,it's working successfully .But there is not running wi fi on my laptop,can you please guide me that how can i use wi fi in my laptop.

Comment: Please raise another question for that issue. Be sure to add the output of `lshw -class network`, showing details about the wireless component. I will not pick up on this, I have too little experience with wifi issues, as mine never failed.